# Error while writing new package in composer.json

Tags: json, laravel-4, dependencies, package, composer-php

```
{
    "name": "marvel/xmen",
    "description": "Mutants saving the world for people who hate them",
    "keywprds": ["mutant", "superhero", "bald", "guy"],
    "homepage": "htp://marvel.com/mutants",
    "time": "1963-09-01",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": 
            [
        {
            "name": "Stan Lee"
            "email": "StanLee@gmail.com"
            "homepage": "http://marvel.com",
            "role": "engineer"  
        }

    ]              
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing commas in the "authors" array. Should be as such:

```
{
    "name": "marvel/xmen",
    "description": "Mutants saving the world for people who hate them",
    "keywprds": ["mutant", "superhero", "bald", "guy"],
    "homepage": "htp://marvel.com/mutants",
    "time": "1963-09-01",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": 
            [
        {
            "name": "Stan Lee",
            "email": "StanLee@gmail.com",
            "homepage": "http://marvel.com",
            "role": "engineer"  
        }

    ]
```

}